# Unity: how to reach lot of Scriptable Object attributes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

(I'm newbie)
I have lot of Scriptable Objects which hold Tile data (forest, desert, etc.) every SO have attributes (like movement cost).
When my Game Object moves I check which type of tile he stepped. It works.
Now I would like to check what is the movement cost of the tile where he stepped. How can I do it?

(I can do it if I declare all the SO at the beginning like:

```
  public TileData forestData;
  public TileData desertData;
```

and so on. And the check the type where the GO stepped. But if I have 100 different tile type it means 100 declaration and 100 if statment.
So how can I do it easier? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use List for this task

```
public List<TileData> Tiles = new List<TileData>();
```

or

```
[SerializeField] private List<TileData> Tiles = new List<TileData>();
```

Some helpful links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html